# How to Generate Same key that is Generated by Previously Random in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have below function that will give me random string if pass any key/ value  to it.

now i want to like that if i pass same key / value to that function then it will give me same string that is generated like previous.

For eg. if i pass string "iv3mw" then it will return output i.e "3vmiw" . now i want like that if i pass again same string "iv3mw" in that case i want same output like previous i.e "3vmiw"

Please suggest me what to do. Below is my code

```
 public string RandomString(string key = "")
    {
        string input = "";
        if (key.Trim() == "")
        {
            input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        }
        else
        {
            input = key;
        }
        var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
                               .Select(x => input[random.Next(0, input.Length)]);
        return new string(chars.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: a RandomString function, that generates the same output based on a key, isn't that just a kind of a hashfunction?

Comment: maybe some sort of hashing function would be better if you want consistent output. There are plenty already available. Depends what you're using this for though.

Comment: You have to use the same seed for the `Random` constructor

Comment: Not anything to do with your actual question but do you expect this to produce a random ordering of the letters in the input or a random string of letters samples from the letters in your input? ie are you aware that an input of `abcde` could produce an output of `aaaaa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An MD5 hash produces the same output for the same input, therefore ensuring your consistency.

A simple example

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
{
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source));
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return sBuilder.ToString();                
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a seed in when you create an instead of `Random`. The same seed will always generate the same sequence of random numbers. The seed is a number so you need a way to get from a string to a number. Here's a working implemenation:

```
public string RandomString(string key = "")
{
    var random = new Random(key.GetHashCode());
    string input = "";
    if (key.Trim() == "")
    {
        input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    }
    else
    {
        input = key;
    }
    var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
                           .Select(x => input[random.Next(0, input.Length)]);
    return new string(chars.ToArray());
}
```

You can see that I've seeded `Random` by using `key.GetHashCode()`. This is a quick and dirty way to get an int from a string. You should evaluate whether it is suitable for whatever purposes you are using this.

One thing worth mentioning is that I believe `GetHashCode` cannot be relied on to give the same value on different systems or on different executions of the same program. It probably will but it isn't guaranteed so if this is a problem you'll want to write your own string to int function.

Comment: `GetHashCode` should never be used for persistence in .NET, it's only guaranteed to be "stable" in the same `AppDomain`. If that's all the OP needs, fine; if he also needs something that persists across domains/application-runs/different computers, he'll need his own hash function as the seed.

Comment: @Luaan: That seems to be covered in my last paragraph (which was added after the initial post in case you think you are going crazy since the post doesn't list the edit)

Comment: @Chirs : In My case suppose if i pass string "iv3mw"  then it will return output i.e "3vmiw" . now i want like that if i pass again same string  "iv3mw" in that case i want same output like previous i.e  "3vmiw".

Comment: In your case it return same string that is pass to the function

Comment: When I run it it does not return the same string that is returned to the function... See https://ideone.com/8gI2uL for that method in a test environment. It is worth mentioning that due to the nature of random numbers it is possible that the string you get out is the same as the one you get in.

Comment: @Chirs : still facing same problem please check http://imgur.com/a/2FPgX

Comment: Err.... Your input is "iw3vm", your output is "iv3mw". In what way are these the same?

Comment: Thanks ..its my mistake but in this case it again generate new string not "3vmiw"

Comment: Are you saying that it generates different outputs for the same input or that it generates different outputs than your original program? I'm not sure how "3vmiw" fits into things here...

Answer (score 1):

You can cache already generated values.

```
Dictionary<string, string> cache = new Dictionary<string, string>

public string RandomString(string key = "")
{
    string input = "";
    if (key.Trim() == "")
    {
        input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    }
    else
    {
        input = key;
    }

    if (cache.ContainsKey(input))
    {
        return cache[input];
    }
    else
    {
        var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)                               
            .Select(x => input[random.Next(0, input.Length)]);
        var value = chars.ToArray();
        cache[input] = value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

*Warning*

As Chris mentioned in his comment, this will not produce consistent results between multiple runs of the program.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this will not produce consistent results between multiple runs of the program. This may or may not be a problem but it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you declare the "random" variable?

I guess your random variable is an instance of the System.Random class. The class has 2 constructors: one without parameters and another one with an Int32 parameter (the random seed value). If you use the 2nd constructor (the one in which you set the seed value), every time you use the same seed value you will obtain the same sequence of random numbers (therefore, the same RandomString).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have declare random variable at class level